# dropbox api usage in django apps, how?

Tags: django, dropbox-api

Could someone show some example about using dropbox api with django?
Dropbox api is installed, readme is done, tests are done, how to go further?

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to do?

Comment: Downvotes for this question are undeserved, but the question does need more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to understand, how oauth works.
Consider the use-case, when you are trying to store uploaded files directly on user's dropbox account.
First of all, you have to register a developer account on dropbox site.
In your django views, a typical workflow is this:

1. ask dropbox for a request token, (it
   notifies them that you will use
   their api soon)

   `dba = auth.Authenticator(app_settings.CONFIG)`

   `request_token = dba.obtain_request_token()`

   > it's in the api's documentation how to
   >   set up the config file
2. than you build an authentication url:

   `authorize_url = dba.build_authorize_url(request_token, callback='http://...'`

   > the user sign in at dropbox.com, than
   >   redirected back to your site
   >
   > you should store now the request
   >   token, but it's only useful to get the
   >   access token!
3. you use the request token to get an
   access token, it's now unique to the
   user.

   `access_token = dba.obtain_access_token(request_token, 'verifier')`

   > leave the verifier blank, it's preserved do future usage!
   >   store the access token, you need it in any further operation(per session)
4. here you are! you should instantiate a client, it's defined
   in the python-specific dropbox
   package

   `drpbx_client = client.DropboxClient('server','content_server','port',dba,access_token)`

   the client is a helper object for file operations:

   `drpbx_client.put_file('dropbox', '/porn/', request.FILES['file'])`

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette):  Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.

Comment: Is it possible to browse the folder list in Dropbox and create subfolders?

Comment: @RobertGrant yes, https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-create-folder

Answer (score 5):

You must use the Dropbox REST api:

http://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs#api-specification

It uses oauth for authentication. Detailed guide and walkthrough can be found here:

http://hueniverse.com/oauth/